# Design (pattern) regarding sharepoint

Tags: design-patterns, sharepoint-2010

i have to implement a sw-design on sharepoint. I dont know how to realize this without programming in sharepoint (in best case only with lists):

i have some kind of QUALITY_TEST and depending on a PRODUCTTYPE it can contain different QUALITY_GROUPS. A QUALITY_GROUP is a grouping of several attributes for the qualitytest.

in real life this means:
a new product arrives and for that product (lets say, this is a banana) we have to make one or more qualitytests. the product type banana can contain quality_groups like appearance with attributes matureness, curve and so on. For a different product (e.g. melone) i need different quality-groups (lets say also appearance (like before in banana) and Taste)

How can i implement this in sharepoint 2010?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Model View Presenter is a common design pattern on SharePoint, you might want to start there and see if it's for you.

[MVP Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649571.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

If the number of different types isn't excessive, you could look into having a different content type for each of them in a list.  You can then have event receivers, workflows, or some other similar mechanism that is dependent on the content type.  Different content types also potentially have a different set of columns, which sounds like it is appropriate to your example.